# Rails link_to_remove not allowing submit

Tags: ruby, forms, submit

I am working on a form. I am using link_to_remove which works to show and hide what I want, but after using it the submit button doesn't do anything. Has anyone run into this or something similar?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: you should paste your codes

Comment: It is because after opening and closing it there were hidden fields still required. A few lines of code to fix it.